# Why the first programme does not work but second works ? and in second why the output is as it gives?

Tags: c++, function, constants, overloading

#### Program 1

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

void fun(const char *a)// passing address of "GeeksForGeeks" by value //
{
cout << "const fun() " << a;
}

void fun(const char *&a){// passing address of "GeeksForGeeks" by reference         //
cout << "const reference fun()" <<a;
}
int main()
{
const char *  ptr = "GeeksforGeeks";
fun(ptr);
return 0;
}
```

error shown

> ```
> In function 'int main()':
> 17:8: error: call of overloaded 'fun(const char*&)' is ambiguous
>  fun(ptr);
>         ^
> 17:8: note: candidates are:
> 6:6: note: void fun(const char*)
>  void fun(const char *a)
>       ^
> 11:6: note: void fun(const char*&)
>  void fun(const char *&a){
>       ^
> ```

#### Program 2

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

void fun(const char *a)// passing address of "GeeksForGeeks" by value //
{
cout << "const fun() " << a;
}

void fun(const char *&a){// passing address of "GeeksForGeeks" by reference         //
cout << "const reference fun()" <<a;
}
int main()
{
const char * const ptr = "GeeksforGeeks";
fun(ptr);
return 0;
}
```

Output

> const fun() GeeksforGeeks

Answer (score 2):

In your first version, there is an ambiguity, because `ptr`, which is of type `const char*` can be cast into `const char*&`. In the second version, there is no ambiguity, because this time `ptr` is of type `const char* const`, which cannot be cast into `const char* &`.

In general `C const` cannot be cast into the type `C&`.

```
void f(int& x) { cout << x; }

void main() {
   int a = 2;
   f(a); // This is fine
   int const b = 2;
   f(b); // Error: 'void f(int &)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'const int' to 'int &'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the first program, you call `fun()` with a pointer to `const char`. Two candidates are available (by value and by reference), and the compiler can't know which one to chose.

In the second program, you call `fun()` with a `const` pointer to `const char`. The compiler then can eliminate the version passed by reference, because this overload doesn't give guarantee that the pointer passed by reference will remain unchanged.

*Additional remark:  if the signature of the second function would give pointer constness  guarantee (aka: `void fun(const char * const &a)` ) the compiler wouldn't be able to choose neither in the first nor in the second case.*

Comment: Sir ,thanks for your answer but i have a doubt that reference variables can be referenced only once. So they are just like const pointers so is there still a need to write "const &a"??? Because for pointers we can make them point to a different address later on once initialised so for them we explicitly need to mention const ptr to const char but refernce variables can only be refered to only one and only one variable .

Comment: @VinayakSangar yes, this means that you can set a reference to a pointer only once, say for example `const char *&p=ptr;`  But once this is done, you use the reference as if it where the original variable.  So in our example, `p="hello";` has the same effect as `ptr="hello";` and `p++` would increment the pointer it refers to (i.e.the content of the pointer ptr).